# Errors not being redirected to an Http handler if redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"

Tags: .net, asp.net, error-handling, httphandler

I see similar questions, but it looks like there were due to an unrelated issue.

in 3.5, I have a custom error handler that logs errors and redirects users. My web.config is set up as such:

```
    <httpHandlers>
                 <add path="error.ashx" type="MySite.Tools.WebErrorLogger, MySite.Tools" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.ashx"
                  redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    </customErrors>
```

When redirectMode is set to `"ResponseRedirect"`, everything works fine (but Server.GetLastError() being null but that seems to be intended)

However, when using `ResponseRewrite`, my handler is not called and I see ASP.Net default error pages. Any idea on how I could do this?

(I unfortunately can't use either an aspx page or do my error handling in global.asax due to other constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have asked a [pretty similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781861/customerrors-does-not-work-when-setting-redirectmoderesponserewrite) in the past.

The solution was converting the error page to a static HTML page.
Surely there must be some kind of error on the dynamic page, but I could not find it.

Comment: Same problem here with Web Forms and Routing, in my case even Static page does not work so I had remove redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"

Answer (score 0):

i came to the same issue and ive found that apparently the reason is the .ashx file, if you use a normal .aspx it will work, it did for me; im still trying to understand how to "enable" the .ashx file extension with REsponseRewrite as it would be more logical rather than using an aspx page in my case. Ive an open thread about this topic here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/aspnetit/thread/7b8f5e36-44a8-40ea-bd73-2e99a1fd42dd

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with an `ashx` handler in current .NET (as of 4.5).

`ResponseRewrite` uses `HttpServerUtility.Execute` which is hardcoded to only allow aspx pages or static files (or legacy ASP pages).