# How to prevent "aspxerrorpath" being passed as a query string to ASP.NET custom error pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

In my ASP.NET web application, I have defined custom error pages in my web.config file as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/default.html">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/PageNotFound.html" />
</customErrors>
```

In the case of a 404 error, my site redirects to the `default.html` page, but it passes "aspxerrorpath" as a query string parameter to the custom error page as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/default.html?aspxerrorpath=/somepathcausederror/badpage.aspx
```

I don't want that behavior.  I want the redirect URL to simply read:

```
http://www.example.com/default.html
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be to create a HttpHandler which catches url's with `aspxerrorpath` in it, and strips it. You could probably do the same with the rewrite module in IIS7 as well.

Answer (score 73):

If you supply your own query string variable when specifying the path, then .NET will NOT tack on the "aspxerrorpath". Who knew?

For example:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="errorpage.aspx?error=1" >
```

This will do the trick.
I had to add this to a bunch of apps since URLScan for IIS by default rejects anything with "aspxerrorpath" in it anyway.

Comment: If you supply your own query string variable, How can you make .net add "aspxerrorpath" to the QueryString you give ?

Comment: Worth mentioning that all you actually need to do is add a "?" to the end to prevent the aspxerrorpath parameter being added. So just:
`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/default.html?"></customErrors>` will do the trick

Comment: Problem with this is, it still sends a status code 302, THEN redirects to the 404 page which is (or should be) status code 404

Comment: @jzm just add `Response.StatusCode = 404;` to the page load method (ASPX) or controller method (MVC) of the 404 page

Answer (score 12):

In the global.asax, catch the 404 error and redirect to the file not found page. I didn't require the aspxerrorpath and it worked a treat for me.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/filenotfound.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        // your global error handling here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just send your own url params to the error page

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/default.html?404"> 
               <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/PageNotFound.html?404" /> 
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd instead implement/use the [Application_Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) event in Global.asax, and do your processing/redirects there.

Providing you call [Server.ClearError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.clearerror.aspx) in that handler, I don't think it will use the customErrors config at all.

Comment: Thanks Demien issue is we still need customErrors config it seems its not possible to control in web.config this behavior(aspxerrorpath query string completely removal)

Answer (score 2):

I use javascript like

```
if (location.search != "") { window.location.href = "/404.html"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove aspxerrorpath=/ and you use response redirect during error handling you'll get exception there will be redirection loop.

Answer (score 1):

Add `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` in the Custom Error like this,

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/NotFound">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"/>
</customErrors>
```

this solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution *(more a workaround..)* I implemented since now to prevent `aspxerrorpath` issue continuing to use ASP.NET CustomErrors support, is redirect to the action that implements Error handling.

These are some step of my solution in an ASP.NET MVC web app context:

> First enable custom errors module in web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/500">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/404"/>
</customErrors>
```

> Then define a routing rule:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Error",
   url: "error/{errorType}/{aspxerrorpath}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Error", errorType = 500, aspxerrorpath = UrlParameter.Optional },
);
```

> Finally implement following action (and related views..):

```
public ActionResult Error(int errorType, string aspxerrorpath)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aspxerrorpath)) {
      return RedirectToRoute("Error", errorType);
   }

   switch (errorType) {
      case 404:
           return View("~/Views/Shared/Errors/404.cshtml");

       case 500:
        default:
           return View("~/Views/Shared/Errors/500.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i prefer not use Web.config. Then i created code above in Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        //Not Found (When user digit unexisting url)
        if(ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            HttpContextWrapper contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");

            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(contextWrapper, routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);
            Response.End();
        }
        else //Unhandled Errors from aplication
        {
            ErrorLogService.LogError(ex);
            HttpContextWrapper contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(contextWrapper, routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

And thtat is my ErrorController.cs

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        return View("~/Views/Shared/SAAS/Error.cshtml", ex);
    }

    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/SAAS/NotFound.cshtml");
    }
}
```

And that is my ErrorLogService.cs

```
//common service to be used for logging errors
public static class ErrorLogService
{
    public static void LogError(Exception ex)
    {
        //Do what you want here, save log in database, send email to police station
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve or handle error request you can insert into Handler try catch statement.
like this:

```
try {
  //  Block of code that generate error
}
catch(Exception e) {
  //  Block of code to handle errors ||| HERE you can put error in your response and handle it without get xhr redirect error.
}
```