# Redirect Loop for Custom Errors Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect

For error handling, I have added the following code to Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.cshtml?">
    </customErrors>
<system.web>
```

And in Global.asax.cs:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    Response.Redirect("/Error.cshtml?");
}
```

However, when the redirect to /Error.cshtml? occurs, there is an error 'This page has a redirect loop'

I've searched through other similar questions (such as [How to solve Redirect Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894254/how-to-solve-redirect-loop)). However, I have no other routes calling Error.cshtml -- so does anyone have any idea what is causing this loop and how I can work around it?

EDIT: There are multiple errors occurring, and therefore the error page redirect is involved  in a redirect loop. Does anyone know of a way to only call Response.Redirect("~/Error.cshtml") once?

EDIT2: If I change the redirect url to a random url outside of the project (such as https://www.facebook.com/), the customError redirect works properly. Still looking for a way to redirect to project page without infinitely looping through the error

Comment: What do you have in Error.cshtml?

Comment: I just have some <h1>test text<h1> type of markup, nothing that should be causing any sort of loop

Comment: @suhMAN, are you sure no errors occur after you call `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: I just tested, and it does look like I continue to end up in the Application_Error function. I found the Error.cshtml actually uses @model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo -- would this have any effect?

Comment: Probably a 404 trying to retrieve the error page.  Try ~/Error.cshtml

Comment: @Dave I use ~/Error.cshtml? because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222226/how-to-prevent-aspxerrorpath-passed-as-a-query-string-in-asp-net-error-pages-t

Comment: Right, so make sure you use the tilde(~) in your global.asax redirect.

Comment: The problem is that Application_Error is being called in a loop (I have no idea why yet) -- anyone have a workaround so that if this loop occurs, the response.redirect is called only once and the loop ends?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Server.ClearError();
```

first to clear the existing error before redirecting.

Comment: I tried adding that line of code, but the same error persists

Answer (score 0):

Add redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" to customErrors section.

Comment: Also get the same error when I added this to customErrors

Comment: @suhMAN Also delete line Response.Redirect("/Error.cshtml?");

Comment: When I delete the Response.Redirect in the Application_Error function, no redirect occurs, and a blank page is displayed

Comment: Are you sure /Error.cshtml is a valid request? Usually .cshtml files are views. You can use it in action, so like request /Common/Error renders Error.cshtml view.