# MVC3 Error handling - not working for 500 type errors in AZURE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

Is there ANYONE out there who has a working solution for handling MVC3 errors in Azure with the IIS7 web server. Note that it has to be this combination. I see many answers but not many for users of Azure web roles. I must have looked at 50+ web pages and found nothing at all except a reference to

```
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>  
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>  
  </system.webServer>  
<configuration>
```

Which still doesn't seem to work and solve my problem

I have my Web.config set up as follows:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/error/notfound" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/notfound"></error>
</customErrors>
```

I checked on the server and the set up is okay.  So now when I browse to a web page that I know will produce a 500 exception I get the following:

```
90b37.cloudapp.net/Error/NotFound?aspxerrorpath=/
```

Seems like it went to the CORRECT error controller and view but then the page is getting changed and I get the standard IIS output (or is it MVC output). Either way what I want to see is the contents of my NotFound page which is what I can see locally with customerror set to "On".

This is what I am getting but not what I want:

```
The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error 
page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's 
<customErrors> etc ...
```

Which is very odd because clearly it just did try to take me to the redirected page.  I hope someone can help. Does anyone know what generates the page snippets that's above here?  Is it IIS or some part of MVC? I have spent the last day on this and got nowhere.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971864/asp-net-mvc-error-handling-remove-aspxerrorpath?

Comment: Also, does this actually relate to Windows Azure? (Is the behavior different in Windows Azure than outside Windows Azure?)

Comment: The problem is that I am getting the ?The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL."  What I expect to get is the contents of my NotFound page. However this appears to be getting replace when run remote.

Comment: I thought Azure only supported MVC2 ? how are u running a MVC 3 application in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the http 404 file not found.

But your error is http 500 internal error.

So your custom error configuration does not catch that error.

You need to catch status code 500.