# HTTP 500, customErrors redirect not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, custom-errors

I'm using MVC2.
My webconfig says

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/internal-server-error">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/internal-server-error" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/not-found" />
</customErrors>
```

My test method says

```
public ActionResult ErrorTest()
{
    var z = 0;
    var x= 3/z;
    return null;
}
```

*I still get the default **Runtime Error*** `Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.`, instead of my custom error method, which is not even called.

Why? *Is this a dev server issue? Will it work on IIS?*

EDIT: Tried it on IIS Express as well, commented out the whole `Application_Error` in `Global.asax.cs`, still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` attribute

[CustomErrors does not work when setting redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781861/customerrors-does-not-work-when-setting-redirectmode-responserewrite)