# How can I use existingResponse="Auto" successfully?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

So I am returning detailed 400 error responses from my MVC web app.  Setting existingResponse="PassThrough" works, but that's not what I want.  I don't want to expose all failures, I only want to expose them when I have custom responses.

Auto, is set by default, but I deliberately set it. However, the documentation says "SetStatus" flag must be set, but I have no idea how to do such a thing. I wrote the following four controller methods in order to test it, and only BadRequestD works. The others set the status code and the status just fine, but the body content is "Bad Request".

```
public ActionResult BadRequestA()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return Content("weeeeee");
}

public ActionResult BadRequestB()
{
    Response.Status = "400 U DUN MESSED UP";
    return Content("weeeeee");
}

public ActionResult BadRequestC()
{
    Response.Status = "400 U DUN MESSED UP";
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return Content("weeeeee");
}

public ActionResult BadRequestD()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    return Content("weeeeee");
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> However, the documentation says "SetStatus" flag must be set, but I have no idea how to do such a thing

It's actually talking about the `fTrySkipCustomErrors` flag/argument to the `IHttpResponse::SetStatus` method in the IIS C++ SDK (see note I added to bottom of [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690943%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). But in ASP.NET the flag is exposed as `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`. So according to:

> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors
>
> Auto = Leaves the response untouched only if the SetStatus flag is set

I would expect to see IIS replace the response with its own html error page content (you can configure what that content is) by default unless you set:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Which is what you're seeing.

---

Additional related info, in MVC5 it seems to act as if that flag is true even if it's false for uncaught exceptions which I don't see in WebForms. As a workaround in Global.asax I'm:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    //code to log error here
    var httpException = error as HttpException;
    Response.StatusCode = httpException != null ? httpException.GetHttpCode() : (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the MVC5 tip! I was having the same problem and your workaround seems to work for me.

Comment: I don't see a `fTrySkipCustomErrors` argument listed in that documentation. Which note are you referring to that you added?

Comment: @xr280xr Looks like they removed the comments section that used to exist at the bottom of the documentation page. I had posted a comment with details indicating documentation doesn't match C++ code that has an extra fTrySkipCustomErrors param.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to have custom responses with 4xx http statuses and still want to use Custom Error Pages here's what you should do:

- set `existingResponse="Auto"` in web.config;
- set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` in your action (one that returns 4xx status and a content);
- clear server error in global.asax (in `Application_Error()` -     `Server.ClearError()`) and re-set the status code (`Reponse.StatusCode = ((HttpException)Server.GetLastError()).GetHttpCode()`)

It's weird that IIS team didn't implement `existingResponse` attribute for specific status codes, so it's impossible to use `existingResponse="PassThrough"` just for one (or few) codes.