# How to return JSON object when Bad Request MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller, bad-request

I am working on MVC 4 project.

I have a Action which executed when Ajax Post request is done.

In some case, which I could exactly determine, I have to set the `Status` property of the `Response` object to `HttpBadRequest` value, AND return JSON object which contains some data to show to the end user.

the problem is I can NOT received the JSON object in the javascript method,
I am receiving something else. and this is because I am setting the Status property of the Response to HttpBadRequest value.

Here is the Details

**Action**

```
// this method will executed when some Ajax Post request.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    // some code here ......

    // in some case we will determine an error like this
    if(error)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        return Json(new
        {
            Message = string.Format(format, values),
            Status = messageType.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

and I want to read this returned JSON object from a javascript function like this

**Javascript**

```
function OnDeleteFailed(data) {
    debugger;
    var try1 = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
    var try2 = JSON.parse(data.responseJSON);
}
```

the problem is that the JSON object will **NOT** filled in the `data` variable of the javascript.
when debugging the Javascript code I get the following in the `data` variable

[image]

The most strange thing that when I delete this line from the Action

```
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

then I received the JSON object correctly and I could to read it as the following

[image]

Note: I am receiving the correct JSON object but, in other Javascript function.
(now I am receiving the JSON object on the `OnDeleteSuccess` function, not in `OnDeleteFailed` function.

So The **Question** is : what the wrong with the code, so the JSON object will not received in the javascript function in case I set the "StatusCode" property of the "Response" object to "BadRequest" value ?

I searched a lot for an answer (from yesterday until now), and after long searching this is the most relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370251/return-json-with-error-status-code-mvc) to me, but unfortunately the solution of that question did not worked for me at all.

**Updated**

here is snippet of the `Web.config` file which set some of `httpErrors` of the IIS.
This update to respond for the suggestion that the cause of the error will come from this point

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Home/PageNotFound" />
   </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably IIS custom errors that is interfering with the response.

Comment: @haim770 I have set some custome error in the web.config file, is this has relation with my issue

Comment: @haim770 I will edit my question to include the snippet of Web.Config file that contains some IIS custom error

Comment: Is `<customErrors mode="Off" />` under `<system.web>`?

Comment: Try to change `existingResponse` to `PassThrough`

Comment: there is no <customError> tag in the <system.web> section of the web.config, do you mean that I have to write this statment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92378/discussion-between-hakam-fostok-and-haim770).

Comment: Allegedly, your `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` should be equivalent. But, try and see

Comment: If you can make use of some `WebAPI` then do something like - `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myErrorJsonObj);`

Comment: @Dayan I could not use the WebAPI

Comment: @haim770 please put your answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Web.Config`, try to change `existingResponse` to `Auto`:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
```

See [Documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)

Comment: According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21271085 - `Auto` is better as it will take `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` into account and would only `Replace` if it's not set.