# Custom Error Pages Do Not Work

Tags: c#, asp.net

While trying to figure out why the Global.asax would not work, I decided to move onto Custom Errors and started running into problems there. I am testing the 404 (Page not found) and it keeps giving me the standard server error page rather than my own page.

I tried setting it on the IIS side of things and that did not work. In fact, having the settings match seemed to throw more errors. I have removed that change to return it to the current issue. I have provided the changes I made to make this error page. Perhaps someone brighter than me can figure out what went wrong?

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" />
```

Any help is widely appreciated! I did check to see if the Error.aspx exists and it does so I know it is not an actual 404 page not found issue

EDIT: Tried suggested duplicate answers and it did not work

EDIT 2: This is the error that appears on the screen

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
> - The URL contains a typographical error.
> - A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> - Create the content on the Web server.
> - Review the browser URL.
> - Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module
>      IIS Web Core
>
> Notification
>      MapRequestHandler
>
> Handler
>      StaticFile
>
> Error Code
>      0x80070002

Comment: I don't know much about the way Custom Errors are handled so if you need any more information please ask!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CustomErrors does not work when setting redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781861/customerrors-does-not-work-when-setting-redirectmode-responserewrite)

Comment: It is also possible that there is an actual error in your Error.aspx page. In such case you should see something like "Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception" somewhere near the top of the YSOD. You can try using a static html file (e.g. ~/Error.htm) just to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the error into the main post

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Looks to be version 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: @JeremyBeare are you using any kind of routing in your application?

Comment: @Kamo - How would I be able to check for you? Any code/features I should look out for?

Comment: @JeremyBeare You should check for any URL rewrites in your code/web.vonfig. It would be helpful if you could attach your web.config file.

Comment: @Kamo - I will post it up as soon as I can - got to cut out the sensitive parts

Comment: @JeremyBeare Sure. I'm just curious - what is the URL you are using to test 404?

Comment: This is the url I am using "http://localhost:00000/blah" (the 0 represent a number)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use a Controller to specific for this, for example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class ErroHttpController : Controller
    {
        [Route("RequestError")]
        public ActionResult RequestError()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return View();
        }

        [Route("NotFound")]
        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return View();
        }

        [Route("InternalError")]
        public ActionResult InternalError()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return View();
        }

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your web.config you should do:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="/RequestError"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/NotFound"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/InternalError"/>
</customErrors>
```

You must skip IIS custom errors, like the code above, in `OnActionExecuting` method.

Comment: OP uses WebForms I suppose.

Comment: It does look to be Webforms