# HTTP errors not consistent using customErrors mode="On"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-error, custom-errors

I am testing custom error handling using similar URLs `http://localhost:52200/<` and `http://localhost:52200/<xyz`. Somehow, I am getting inconsistent results.

**Web.Config:**

```
<!--MVC pipeline-->
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>

<!--IIS pipeline-->
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

When `customErrors mode="Off"`, both return identical `HTTP 400 Bad Request`:

[image]

However, when `customErrors mode="On"`, only `http://localhost:52200/<` returns `HTTP 400 Bad Request` and then redirects to `Error.aspx`.

Now, `http://localhost:52200/<xyz` returns `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` and goes to:

[image]

When I remove [ResponseRewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781861/customerrors-does-not-work-when-setting-redirectmode-responserewrite), both return `HTTP 302 Found` and redirect to `Error.aspx`. I do not want this because I lose the http error code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! For a reason unknown to me, MVC pipeline requires `defaultRedirect` to point toward a `.html` file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error.html">
```

Adding `Response.ContentType = "text/html";` in `Global.asax.cs` avoids a known issue where the error page would render as text:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    if (exception is HttpException httpException)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.StatusCode = httpException != null ? httpException.GetHttpCode() : (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
}
```

Also, `Response.StatusCode` ensures that the correct HTTP error code reaches the client (e.g. 400, 503, etc.) instead of a 200.

With these 2 blocks in `web.config` and `global.asax.cs` and no change to IIS, both `http://localhost:52200/<` and `http://localhost:52200/<a` now return `HTTP 400 Bad Request` and display `Error.html` as expected.